# Set Image contrast in android

Tags: android, image, android-emulator

I want make application simple image editor in android . For the first I want to make application to change contrast image with seekbar in android . I didnt find tutorial about this , can u help me?? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try out the following tutorial:

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/